# Brokered UWP Component - Administrator privilege

Tags: c#, uwp, elevated-privileges

I am trying to use a 3rd party API to print an html file. When I use vendor's SDK in WinForm application, it fails during InternetExplorer operations. (error is below) So I found out that process should run only on "Administrator" privilege. And then, application and print operations work well.

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)): Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IConnectionPoint.Unadvise(Int32
>   dwCookie)    at
>   SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_EventProvider.remove_TitleChange(DWebBrowserEvents2_TitleChangeEventHandler
>   )    at
>   SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass.remove_TitleChange(DWebBrowserEvents2_TitleChangeEventHandler
>   )

My question starts after that. I have to use same API to print in a brokered UWP app. Say it is a assigned-access / kiosk application. I know UWP cannot run with user elevation, but i assume brokered app should have some settings to run, basically "dllhost.exe" as administrator. Because of the application should run on assigned access mode, I cannot set assigned access user as Administrator. (I have doubt it will work even if i set it)

Are there any possibility to run dllhost.exe as admin? Or any other suggestion for issue?

Comment: Since you already have an installer for your brokered component, have you tried installing an EXE alongside the brokered component that is set up to auto-elevate? Then I believe you should be able to call CreateProcess (or Process.Start) from your brokered component to launch the elevated process to perform whatever operation requires elevation.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Yes, I thought about it, and it seems working. But my priority was making it as in-process operation to communicate with API properly. I am planning to communicate with MSMQ currently. Do I have any option to communicate with EXE?

Comment: I think any standard Win32 inter-process communication mechanism would be available here (sockets, RPC, etc.). The right choice depends on your requirements, like complexity, frequency, volume of your communication.

Answer (score 0):

If compared with WinForms framework, UWP has significantly different security model. Same issue for the list of APIs available, and for app-level lifetime schema. Thus, I would suspect you have to contact your vendor for UWP-compatible SDK.

Comment: I believe even UWP-compatible SDK will not solve my problem.  Because I am invoking operations in sand-boxed .NET environment using side-loding. Meaning, my code runs on .NET but process started by UWP. So, I assumed sand-boxed environment should have some privilege assigning or run-as infrastructure.

Comment: UWP intends sand-boxing from very beginning (this is why it has significantly less APIs available). So, for instance, you can NOT access "drive C:" in UWP neither call "CreateFileEx" as they're prohibited, regardless side-loading or MS Store being used for the app deployment.